# How do I import dependencies after declaring them in build.gradle?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am just starting to work on android studio and beginning to explore the world of Gradle. So I created a project in Android Studio, opened up `build.gradle` and added dependencies like the below:

```groovy
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.1.0'
}
```

After this I notice a tip popping up on `build.gradle` which says:

> You can configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources. 
>   It will provide IDE with Gradle API/DSL documentation"

I ignore this and I don't find either timber or retrofit in the external libraries after I try building the project. Obviously I was missing something. I believed that after declaring the dependencies and clicking build, the particular libraries will be auto imported but yes, I was wrong.

So I agree and apply the tip which popped up on `build.gradle` and then the project got refreshed, post which all the dependencies were available in the "External Libraries".

So the question is:

- **How do I ensure to have all the dependencies in place after declaring it in `build.gradle`?**

I have read that I can do this the GUI way by clicking on import modules but I want to find out if there are other ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using Android Studio 0.4.3, please upgrade to it -- there are bugfixes in that version that prevent newly-added dependencies from being completely visible to your project in the IDE (though it would actually build okay). If you're not already running 0.4.3, that will probably fix your problem.

As for the message about configuring the Gradle wrapper to use sources, that applies to having the wrapper download a version of Gradle itself that includes the source code to Gradle. Doing this allows the IDE to be smarter about syntax highlighting when you're editing **build.gradle** files from the IDE. What that tip does is it changes this URL in your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file from this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
```

to this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Perfect! But do I have to click on"Sync Project with gradle files" everytime after adding the dependencies, or just a rebuild would do?

Comment: Any time you edit the build.gradle files by hand, you have to click on that button. We'll make it smarter in the future (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63151) but for now you have to.

Comment: @ScottBarta Did anyone find a way to force ".. distribution with sources .." from the command line? I run `./gradlew wrapper` to update but it always falls back to `-bin.zip` instead of `-all.zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can check your dependencies from Android Studio GUI using following steps :

- Go to to `File > Project Structure` or Right click on project and
  choose `Open Module Settings`
- Opened window will have all your modules listed in left side pane and
  some tabs on right pane.
- Select the module for which you want to check the Dependencies and
  choose `"Dependencies"` tab from Right pane.

You will see all dependencies there which you have defined in your `build.gradle` file, also using **"+"** icon available on right pane you can add more.

[image: Dependencies GUI]