# Android Studio Adding Dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have crated an app with multiple modules, Then i have linked them as Library files.
Now in order for me to create an onClick button to take me to the next module, i believe i have to make a dependency between the two modules.
When i try to add the dependencies i get this error:

before adding dependencies

[image]

after adding dependencies

[image]

the error

[image]

i am trying to create a button that calls another activity called MainActivity in Formupload module.

Comment: You should add the text of the images; or upload the image on Stack Overflow. The service used causes problems for Stack Overflow - the image could not be retrieved. Also see [How to add dependencies in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31839214/608639), [How do I import dependencies after declaring them in build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21511446/608639), etc.

Comment: Done, the link you added does not provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your libraries-formupload has a `build.gradle` for an app (main) module.

1. On top of you `libraries-formupload/build.gradle` you have

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

but it must be:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Make sure all modules `build.gradle` files have correct import statements.

2. `applicationId`, `buildTypes` and `productFlavors` also belong to the app module. Move them there.

Comment: Error:(45, 0) Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Amr\AndroidStudioProjects\Firebase2\app\libraries\firstscreen\build.gradle">Open File</a>